# TypeError: 'addNode' is not a function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I wrote a simple JavaScript p5 app (with p5.js) to create a BST data structure. When running this with Firefox, it's showing me `TypeError: this.root.addNode is not a function`
Can anyone please help? This is the full code (error is in line 20)

```
var tree;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  tree = new Tree();
  tree.addValue(5);
  tree.addValue(3);
  console.log(tree);
}

function Tree() {
  this.root = null;
}

Tree.prototype.addValue = function (val) {
  var n = new Node(val);
  if (this.root == null) {
    this.root = n;
  } else {
      this.root.addNode(n);
  }
}

Tree.prototype.addNode = function (n) {
  if (n.value < this.value)
    if (this.left == null) {
      this.left = n;
    } else {
      this.left.addNode(n);
    }
  } else if (n.value > this.value) {
    if (this.right == null) {
      this.right = n;
    } else {
      this.right.addNode(n);
    }
  }
}

function Node(val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`root` is simply a property that you later assign to be a `Node`. You assign the prototype function `addNode` to `Tree`, `Node` doesn't have that. Either  set

```
this.root = new Tree();
```

or assign the prototype method `addNode` to `Node` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, this is how you might implement it using `class` keyword which handles a lot of manual prototype stuff handling for you so it is a little less error prone.

```
class Node {
  constructor(key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  _insert(target, key) {
    if (target.key > key) {
      if (!target.left) {
        target.left = new Node(key);
      } else {
        this._insert(target.left, key);
      }
    } else {
      if (!target.right) {
        target.right = new Node(key);
      } else {
        this._insert(target.right, key);
      }
    }
  }

  insert(key) {
    if (!this.root) {
      this.root = new Node(key);
    } else {
      this._insert(this.root, key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could use classes I guess, but I was trying to do it recursively. Anyways, I'll try it. Thanks man

Comment: @Alexi the above code is recursive, both `_insert` calls itself as well as `insert`. You can't actually get more recursive than this considering value insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tree;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  tree = new Tree();
  tree.addValue(5);
  tree.addValue(3);

  console.log(tree);
}

const Tree = function () {
  this.root = null;
};

Tree.prototype.addValue = function (val) {
  var n = new Node(val);
  if (this.root == null) {
    this.root = n;
  } else {
    this.root.addNode(n);
  }
};

const Node = function (val) {
  this.value = val;
  this.right = null;
  this.left = null;
};

Node.prototype.addNode = function (n) {
  if (n.value < this.value) {
    if (this.left == null) {
      this.left = n;
    } else {
      this.left.addNode(n);
    }
  } else if (n.value > this.value) {
    if (this.right == null) {
      this.right = n;
    } else {
      this.right.addNode(n);
    }
  }
};

console.log("end!");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).